# How to block songs on Spotify

Tags: spotify

After using Spotify for more than five years, I'm meeting the ceiling and Spotify only recommends songs I've already listened to, including those I don't like.
Is there a way to block the songs I do not like? The dislike button isn't there in my Spotify 2020 on Mac.

Alternatively, any suggestions for algorithms better than Spotify?

Comment: why don't you ask Spotify?

Comment: @jsotola the second question would not be welcomed by them